# Use de Moivre's formula to write $\cos(n\theta)$ as a polynomial of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Use the binomial formula and de Moivre’s formula to write
>   $$
>  \cos n\theta + i \sin n\theta
>  = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \cos^{n-k} \theta (i \sin \theta)^k
>  \quad
>  (n = 0, 1, 2, \dotsc).
> $$
>   Then define the integer $m$ by means of the equations
>   $$
>  m =
>  \begin{cases}
>   n/2     & \text{if $n$ is even}, \\
>   (n-1)/2 & \text{if $n$ is odd}
>  \end{cases}
> $$
>   and use the above summation to show that
>   $$
>  \cos n\theta
>  = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n}{2k} (-1)^k \cos^{n-2k} \theta \sin^{2k} \theta
>  \quad
>  (n = 0, 1, 2, \dotsc).
> $$

I can use the binomial formula and de Moivre's formula to get the first equation
but after I define $m$ as above, I don't know how to change $k$ to $2k$ and get the formula.

Comment: You need to cancel $isin\theta$ with $-isin\theta$ how would you do it?

Comment: $\cos(n\theta)$ is the **real** part of the sum in the first equation. The real part is given by the sum over the *even* $k$. For such $k$, let $k=2j$. Write down the real part as a sum over $j$. Then change the dummy summation variable to $k$. They really should not have used $k$ for the last expression, it just confuses people.

Comment: it really helps,thx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos n\theta + i\sin n\theta=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\cos^{n-k}\theta(i\sin\theta)^k\tag{1}$$
$$\cos (-n\theta) + i\sin (-n\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\cos^{n-k}(-\theta)(i\sin(-\theta))^k$$
$$\cos n\theta - i\sin n\theta=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\cos^{n-k}\theta\cdot(-1)^k(i\sin\theta)^k\tag{2}$$
$\dfrac{(1)+(2)}2$:
$$\cos n\theta=\sum_{k=even}^n{n \choose k}\cos^{n-k}\theta(i\sin\theta)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor}{n \choose 2k}\cos^{n-2k}\theta(i\sin\theta)^{2k}\\=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor}{n \choose 2k}\cos^{n-2k}\theta\cdot i^{2k}\sin^{2k}\theta=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor}{n \choose 2k}\cos^{n-2k}\theta\cdot (-1)^{k}\sin^{2k}\theta$$

Comment: it really helps,thx a lot!